# How to use count() in @Html.ActionLink in view page? MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("SubC2B", "Index", "SubC2B", new { id = item.Id }, null)
        @item.subindex.Count()
    </td>
<tr>
}
```

result is [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWEaw.png)

if i want to use @item.subindex.Count() replace in "SubC2B" how can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just has to be a string value

```
 @Html.ActionLink(item.subindex.Count().ToString(), "Index", "SubC2B", new { id = item.Id }, null)
```